# How do you manualy disable headphone jack?

Tags: headphone-jack

I have an Android (Samsung Galaxy 3) it seems that my headphone jack has malfunctioned is some way as it will automatically detect that headphones are pluged in when they are not. I can still plug in headphones and hear music etc. However I would like to hear my pgone without headphones even if it means no headphone jack.

Comment: Did you do this phone into water recently? Something similar happened me once.

Comment: Try cleaning the headphone jack, maybe with a needle or something thin. Get as much stuff out as you can.